# Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '[string | undefined]'

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

I am developing a typescript project.
Currently, my challenge is the ts(2322) error.

Here is my code.

```
import {
  BASE_URL,
  AIRTABLE_BASE_ID,
  AIRTABLE_TABLE_STUDENT,
  AIRTABLE_TABLE_CLASSES,
  API_KEY,
} from './../../config/config';
// A mock function to mimic making an async request for data
export function fetchCount(amount = 1) {
  return new Promise<{ data: number }>((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: amount }), 500)
  );
}

// Result object
interface Result {
  records: [
    {
      id: string;
      createdTime: string;
      fields: {
        Name?: string;
        Students?: [string];
        Classes?: [string];
      };
    }
  ];
}

// Class info object
interface ClassInfo {
  Name: string | undefined;
  Students: [string | undefined];
}

// fetch airtable data by url
const fetchData = (endpoint: string) => {
  return fetch(endpoint, {
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
    }),
  }).then((res) => res.json());
};

// fetch classes record ids by student name
const fetchClassesByStudent = (name = '') => {
  const endpoint = `${BASE_URL}${AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}${AIRTABLE_TABLE_STUDENT}?filterByFormula=Name="${name}"&fields[]=Classes`;
  return fetchData(endpoint);
};

// fetch classes names and students ids from classes record ids
const fetchClassesInfo = (classids: [string]) => {
  const endpoint = `${BASE_URL}${AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}${AIRTABLE_TABLE_CLASSES}?filterByFormula=OR(${classids
    .map((val) => `RECORD_ID() = "${val}"`)
    .join(', ')})`;
  return fetchData(endpoint);
};

// fetch students names from students ids
const fetchStudentsNames = (studentids: [string]) => {
  const endpoint = `${BASE_URL}${AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}${AIRTABLE_TABLE_STUDENT}?filterByFormula=OR(${studentids
    .map((val) => `RECORD_ID() = "${val}"`)
    .join(', ')})&fields[]=Name`;
  return fetchData(endpoint);
};

// fetch class and its students list
export function fetchList(name = '') {
  const classList: [ClassInfo?] = [];
  fetchClassesByStudent(name).then((res: Result) => {
    const classids = res.records?.[0].fields.Classes;
    if (classids) {
      fetchClassesInfo(classids).then((res: Result) => {
        res.records.map((value) => {
          if (value.fields.Students && value.fields.Name) {
            fetchStudentsNames(value.fields.Students).then((res: Result) => {
              const eachClass: ClassInfo = {
                Name: value.fields.Name,
                Students: res.records.map((value) => value.fields.Name),
              };
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

If I change the ClassInfo interface to

```
interface ClassInfo {
  Name: string | undefined;
  Students: (string | undefined)[];
}
```

Then no error.
I just want to know what is difference between (T)[] and [T].
Also want to know if the array could have no value, and what I should put in the interface.

Comment: Doesn’t `[T]` denote an array containing exactly one element of type `T`?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays, which specifically calls out and links to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Yes, T can be string or string | undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [an introductory chapter of TypeScript’s handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays):

> ### Arrays
>
> To specify the type of an array like `[1, 2, 3]`, you can use the syntax `number[]`; this syntax works for any type (e.g. `string[]` is an array of strings, and so on). […]
>
> > Note that `[number]` is a different thing; refer to the section on [Tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).

TypeScript can ascribe types to arrays in two ways: `T[]` denotes an array of arbitrary length (possibly zero), which may vary at runtime, and whose elements are all of type `T`.

But TypeScript also supports arrays of fixed length whose individual elements are assigned independent types, which are written `[T]`, `[T, U]`, `[T, U, V]`, etc.  The latter kind of array is termed a *tuple* in TypeScript, but expect that terminology to change as [the JavaScript Record and Tuple proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple/) advances and becomes integrated into the language.  Here’s how the handbook describes them:

> #### Tuple Types
>
> A *tuple type* is another sort of `Array` type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions.
>
> ```ts
> type StringNumberPair = [string, number];
> ```
>
> Here, `StringNumberPair` is a tuple type of string and number. […] To the type system, `StringNumberPair` describes arrays whose 0 index contains a string and whose 1 index contains a number.

To apply it to your specific example: `(string | undefined)[]` is an array of any number of elements, each of which may be either a `string` or `undefined` independently of the others.  `[string | undefined]` is an array containing exactly one element, which is either a `string` or `undefined`.  As such, the latter is assignable to the former, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

`[T]` is a tuple type. It denotes an array with **one** element of type `T`. `T[]` means an array with elements of type `T`.